# What's $(2^\mathfrak{c})^{<2^\mathfrak{c}}$?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, cardinals

I'm wondering if $\lambda = (2^{\mathfrak{c}})^{<2^\mathfrak{c}} = \sup_{\kappa < 2^\mathfrak{c}} 2^{\mathfrak{c}\cdot \kappa}$ can be calcuted without invoking the general continuum hypothesis and related. So far I can see $\lambda \geq 2^\mathfrak{c}$ and equality holds under GCH.

More precisely I want to know if ZFC proves $\lambda = 2^\mathfrak{c}$.

This cardinal appeared when I tried to calculate the amount of pseudocompact subspaces of $\beta\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be anything. Suppose that $\mathfrak c=\aleph_1$, $2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_3$, and $2^{\aleph_2}=\mu$, for any $\mu$, such that $\operatorname{cf}(\lambda)\geq\aleph_3$.

Then $\lambda=\mu$ in that case. Since $\mu$ can be as small or as large as you'd like it to be, with the obvious constraint on cofinality, there's no good way of saying what it may or may not be.

Two caveats here are:

1. If $2^\frak c$ is a successor cardinal, say $\mu^+$, then $\lambda=2^\mu$.
2. If $2^\frak c$ is a limit cardinal, then it must have uncountable cofinality, and so the question is really about the behaviour of the continuum function below $2^\frak c$.

Comment: Oh okay, so I understand it, $\mathfrak{c}= \aleph_1, 2^{\aleph_1} = \aleph_3, 2^{\aleph_2} = \aleph_4$ is independent of ZFC, yes?

Comment: I recall there is a theorem about the continuum function on regular cardinals can be whatever we want as long as it satisfies that it's increasing and some condition on cofinality, but I it didn't make much sense to me and I was explained that this is a statement for models or something and it should work for independence if we put "concrete" values into it, is that what's happening here?

Comment: Yes, the continuum function on regular cardinals is entirely beyond the reach of ZFC, this is Easton's theorem. And indeed, a very small part of it is what we are doing here.